# How to obtain output in a scratch memory layer when using processing.run() in qgis plugins

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, memory-layer

I am writing a python plugin for QGIS and I need to use an inbuilt tool "Distance to nearest hub (line to hub)" in the QGIS processing toolbox. The following line is supposed to give me the desired output as a scratch layer.

> `processing.run("qgis:distancetonearesthublinetohub", {'INPUT':base_layer,'HUBS':destination_layer, 'FIELD':id,'UNIT':measuring_unit,'OUTPUT':'memory'})`

However, I get the following error when using this command.

> Could not create layer memory.gpkg: Creation of data source failed (OGR error: sqlite3_open(memory.gpkg) failed: unable to open database file)

But still, this works quite fine when I replace the last argument "memory" with a xxxxx.shp filepath and the output gets stored in a shapefile. And this output looks as expected when this xxxxx.shp is loaded into the project. So, the problem is, the output cannot be stored as a scratch layer.

I have looked up these forums and couldn't find an answer that really fixed this issue.

Comment: Try `'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'` instead of `'memory'`. If you want to load the result use `processing.runAndLoadResults` instead of `processing.run`

Comment: @BenW Thank you very much for your swift response! This is exactly what I was after. Couldn't find this in the documentation for some reason. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem, you are very welcome:-)